# Additive alpha blending with masks

Tags: jquery, html, svg, svg-filters

I want to create the illusion of glowing light in the dark, in the example I have two rect masks on top of each other but as you can see there is an alpha blending issue. Is there a way to merge the 2 mask rects together?

Mouse-over the window on the codepen link to see what I mean.

```
<svg width="976" height="549" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="lightsource">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black" />
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
        </radialGradient>
        <mask id="mask1" x="0" y="0" width="976" height="549">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="976" height="549" fill="white" />
        <ellipse ry="60" rx="64" id="svg_1" cy="122.5" cx="101.5" stroke-width="none" fill="url(#lightsource)"/>
        <ellipse ry="60" rx="64" id="svg_2" cy="175.5" cx="216" stroke-width="none" fill="url(#lightsource)"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <rect x="0" y="0" id="cool" width="976" height="549" mask="url(#mask1)" fill="black" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cFAqx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use a `<feBlend>` filter. In this case, it would make more sense to blend two copies of the same gradient mask after offsetting them in the positive and negative X directions.

```
<defs>
  <radialGradient id="lightsource">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="black" />
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
  </radialGradient>
  <mask id="mask1" x="0" y="0" width="976" height="549">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="976" height="549" fill="white" />
    <ellipse filter="url(#f1)" ry="60" rx="64" id="svg" cy="122.5" cx="101.5" stroke-width="none" fill="url(#lightsource)"/>
  </mask>
  <filter id="f1" x="-100%" y="0" width="300%" height="100%">
    <feOffset result="light1" in="SourceGraphic" dx="-50" dy="0" />
    <feOffset result="light2" in="SourceGraphic" dx="50" dy="0" />
    <feBlend in="light1" in2="light2" mode="darken" />
  </filter>
</defs>
```

Here, the `<filter>` element creates two copies of the ellipse and combines them with a `darken` filter. I've updated your codepen to show it working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LtcIj

**Edit:** Actually, a `multiply` blend might look better.

Comment: This is totally the answer but in experimenting, I've broken the codepen. Am I able to add a third light sourcegraphic?

Comment: An `<feBlend>` element can only take two inputs, but you can cascade from one to another by adding a `result` attribute in one and using it as the `in` or `in2` attribute of another. Here you go: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DnEki

Comment: I need to be able to programmatically position these over the background but if you move one around like here http://jsfiddle.net/krazyjakee/Lyaa6894/, there is limited width of how far it can move away without disappearing into darkness. Is there a limit on the filter size?

Comment: nvm, for some reason setting the filter width and height to "10" fixed this... strange